# .split() returns list of individual charachters instead of splitting it as the spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
n = input("input n: ")
n.split()
print(n, len(n))
```

Say the input is: 100 400, seperated by a space, .split() returns a list of all the individual digits, as well as the space between them, instead of the two numbers such that len(n) = 7, and n[0] = 1 instead of 100.

Comment: `n` is still the original string, not the list returned by `n.split()`.

Comment: yeah thanks, thought it worked like the .sort() fucntion but ig it doesn't

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) first?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't replacing `n` with the return value of `n.split()`.

```
>>> n = "100 400"
>>> n.split()
['100', '400']
>>> n
"100 400"
```

You need to save that return value.

```
>>> x = n.split()
>>> print(x, len(x))
['100', '400'] 2
```

You can, of course, assign the result back to the name `n` (although that can cause some issues if you are using `mypy` to check  your code, as it will infer a static type of `str` for `n` and complain about an attempt to assign a list to the name).

Comment: thanks, thought it worked like the .sort() fucntion

Comment: `sort`, though, starts with a list and modifies it in place. You can't modify a `str` value in place (at all, really) and have it turn into a value of a different type.

Answer (score 0):

You might get the expected results if you do this:

```
n = input("input n: ")
n = n.split()
print(n, len(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the original output of `n` and not a list of your original variable split. You need to access your list variable **after** you've split it:

```
    n = input("input n: ")
    after = n.split()

    print(after, len(after))
```

Yields:

`['100', '400'] 2`

If you wanted to access individual indexes, you could iterate through the list `after` and access each index, like so:

```
    n = input("input n: ")
    after = n.split()
        for x in range(0, len(after)):
        print(after[x])
```

Which yields:

```
100
400
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to split a string by spaces use

```
n.split(' ')
```